# What is my net revenue per square meter?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Textbook problem:**

> I buy seedlings at \$$a$ per dozen and plant them at a density of $x$ seedlings per square meter.  If each square meter requires a total of $t$ hours of labor (from planting to harvesting) at \$$b$ per hour, and the yield is worth \$$r$ per seedling at the market, what is my net revenue per square meter?

**Question:** The revenue, as I understand it, would be just $rx$ dollars per square meter. So by *net* revenue do they really just mean profit which is the total revenue $rx$ minus the various costs (i.e., of the seedlings and of the labor)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exercise specifically uses the phrase "net revenue".  That is the money you actually put in your pocket.

A square meter holds x seedlings so x/12 dozen at a cost of ax/12 dollars.  That square meter requires t hours of labor at b dollars per hour so a total bt dollars for labor.  That's a total cost of ax/12+ bt dollars.

You sell the x seedlings for r dollars each so a GROSS revenue of rx dollars.  The NET revenue is rx- ax/12- bt.

Comment: That's the answer I came up with too, but I interpret that to be "profit" as in "revenue minus costs" which is what prompted my question.  I thought "net revenue" was more like total/gross revenue minus discounts or something, not minus costs.